# how to center align data list and its button

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-datalist

I am trying to center align a datalist along with its button and increasing the size of its datalist box. I tried putting align="center" in the input list, but no changes got. Also dont know how to increase its size of the box and making it responsive. Please help

code:

```
<input list="category" name="category" id="textcat">
<datalist id="category">
  <option id="www.google.com" value="fruits" />
  <option id="www.fb.com" value="animals" />
  <option id="www.ymail.com" value="vechiles" />
  <option id="www.msn.com" value="ornaments" />
</datalist>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="submit">
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to center align all the elements or something else

Comment: @AbhinavS.Chauhan yes to center align the datalist textbox and the button along with it

Comment: Then you could place all your elements in a div and apply text-align css property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using proper *markup* you can do this easily ! Just add one extra `div` with bootstrap default class `text-center`. Try this code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="text-center">
        <form action="" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" list="category " name="category " id="textcat ">
            <datalist id="category ">
              <option id="www.google.com " value="fruits " />
              <option id="www.fb.com " value="animals " />
              <option id="www.ymail.com " value="vechiles " />
              <option id="www.msn.com " value="ornaments " />
            </datalist>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <input class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="btn" type="button" value="submit ">
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is possible for me to increase the width of the text box and height of it, and also making the textbox to the center and middle of the page

Comment: Yes ! you can do it by using `col- * - *` classes example `col-md-12` `col-xs-10` and more by using bootstrap default class

Comment: <div class="text-center col-md-12 col-xs-10"> but remains with its same size

Comment: now the submit button got editable, when i click over it i can type in that button

Comment: Please stop posting identical "try this <link>" comments below questions and answers. If you have constructive feedback to give to a user about their post, *give it*, stop posting hundreds of links to generic links to the documentation below every question you come across.